# How to make a cone frustum

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've tried a lot to make a 3D model of frustum of cone but have been unsuccessful. How can I model one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply add a *Cone* primitive and adjust the radius of the top *(Radius 2)* and then adjust the length and or bottom radius as needed.

[image]

Comment: A huge thanks,@iKlsR. This works very well

Answer (score 3):

Starting with a default primitive of a cone and a cube from the add object menu. Place the cube so that it covers the tip you want to cut away.

Add a *Boolean Modifier* to the cone and set *Object* to *Cube* and *Operation* to Difference.
After the modifier is applied you can remove the cube:

[image]

[image]

#### Alternatively

Start with a Cylinder select the top face in *Edit Mode* and scale the tip <kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: The problem with *Boolean* is that it likes to mess with (read: destroy) your topology. *Knife Project* might be cleaner.